# Can't use SDL2 variables in Block scope

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I'm programming with SDL2, but I cannot grasp the reason behind the following. This works:

```
SDL_Window  *window;
SDL_Surface *screen_surface;
SDL_Surface *picture;

auto initWindow(void)
{…}
auto loadMedia(void)
{…}
auto close(void)
{…}

int main(void)
{
    initWindow();
    loadMedia();
    …
    close();
}
```

However this does not:

```
auto initWindow(SDL_Window *window, SDL_Surface *screen_surface)
{…}
auto loadMedia(SDL_Surface *picture, std::string resource)
{…}
auto close(SDL_Window *window, SDL_Surface *picture)
{…}

int main(void)
{
    SDL_Window  *window;
    SDL_Surface *screen_surface;
    SDL_Surface *picture;
    initWindow(window, screen_surface);
    loadMedia(picture, "resource_file.bmp");
    …
    close(window, picture);
}
```

The only difference is that I take `window`, `screen_surface` and `picture` out of *file scope* and put it into *block scope* (i.e. the main function), and instead of referencing global variables inside these functions, I use parameters.
However when I try to run this, it displays a white screen, but doesn't display any errors. I don't understand what goes wrong here.

Comment: Good candidate for stepping through both versions with your IDE's debugger to see what the difference is.

Comment: What does `void f(int x) {x = 5;}` `int main() {int i = 7; f(i); printf("%d\n", i);}` print, and why?

Comment: To elaborate `initWindow(SDL_Window *window, SDL_Surface *screen_surface)` you are passing **copies** of the pointers in this declaration.

Comment: @immibis `7`, because call-by-value, but this is call-by-reference, isn't it?

Comment: @henrikgiesel No? C has no such thing as call-by-reference.

Comment: @immibis Then what's `void f(int *x);` compared to `void f2(int x);`?

Comment: @henrikgiesel In the first `x` is an `int*`, and in the second it's an `int`?

Comment: @JesseGood I'm passing copies, but they still point to the same spot in memory

Comment: @henrikgiesel: Yes, they point to the same spot in memory before you call the `initWindow` function. However, inside the `initWindow` you _change_ what the *copied* pointer points to. The problem is this does not affect the pointer declared in `main`, you are **only modifying the *copied* pointer** inside `initWindow`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer : I have never done any SDL programming, so this is just an answer based on common sense and what I could read from the comments.

Say your `initWindow` function sets some value to the `window` variable. When that variable is declared in a global scope, modifications to it are also seen by all the other functions that use this variable.

This changes drastically when you change that variable to be a function parameter. Basing on the code you provided :

```
auto initWindow(SDL_Window *window, SDL_Surface *screen_surface)
{
    window = SDL_GetWindow(); /* or something */
}

int main(void)
{
    SDL_Window  *window;
    SDL_Surface *screen_surface;
    initWindow(window, screen_surface);
    /* some other code that uses 'window' */
}
```

**Only** the `window` in `initWindow` is actually set to the value of `SDL_GetWindow`. The `window` variable inside `main` is not changed : all the other functions that need to use it in `main` will be accessing an uninitialized variable, which is undefined behaviour. You also have a resource leak, since you're now never able to free what you got from `SDL_GetWindow`. `initWindow` actually receives a **copy** of `window`, a one that's totally unrelated to the `window` in `main`.

Seeing how you're using C++, the best way around this is to have `initWindow` accept a reference to the `window` variable, like this :

```
auto initWindow(SDL_Window *&window, SDL_Surface *&screen_surface)
{
    window = SDL_GetWindow(); /* or something */
}

int main(void)
{
    SDL_Window  *window;
    SDL_Surface *screen_surface;
    initWindow(window, screen_surface);
    /* some other code that uses 'window' */
}
```

Now, the `window` variable inside `main` will be updated with what `initWindow` does with it, and later code that uses `window` in `main` will access the resource that was acquired via `SDL_GetWindow`.

However, C++ allows you to manage resources in a more efficient way via the usage of constructors and destructors, a concept known as RAII (Resource Acquisition Is Initialization). Look for C++ wrappers around the SDL objects which will make your life much easier, and if you don't, spend a while to write your own, or make them work with `std::unique_ptr` (or `std::shared_ptr` if you know that you need it). You'll thank yourself for it later on.

Comment: The one thing I would do slightly differently is that instead of using `SDL_Window *&window` as the argument, I would use `SDL_Window **window`. That forces you to use `&window` at the call site, making it clear at a glance that the value could change. (but this is just a style issue, others might not agree.)

Comment: @Alex : sure. I thought having a `SDL_Window**` would be too C-ish. ;)

Comment: It works, but I wonder, why is the behavior like this? I know that `SDL_Window` is some kind of `struct` (SDL2 is actually a C library). When I declare a `struct` myself, make a pointer to that struct and pass that to a function just like I did, here, it works just as expected.