# Why do I have to pass a pointer to a pointer in this case

Tags: c, pointers, pass-by-pointer

This question is builds on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35328364/cant-use-sdl2-variables-in-block-scope) from me.

There I had this construct. It uses SDL2:

```
void init_window(SDL_Window *window)
{
    window = SDL_CreateWindow(…);
}

int main(void)
{ 
    SDL_Window  *window;
    init_window(window);
}
```

This didn't work. The answer suggested, I used `*&window` as a function parameter instead, and it worked great.
I rewrote the `*&window` to `**window` as the following:

```
void init_window(SDL_Window **window)
{
    *window = SDL_CreateWindow(…);
}

int main(void)
{ 
    SDL_Window  *window;
    init_window(&window);
}
```

And it also works. But I still don't understand why the first version doesn't work. I looked up the [implementation details of SDL_Window](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_Surface) and it's just a normal `typedef` of a struct to put it into ordinary namespace. [SDL_CreateWindow](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateWindow) returns `SDL_Surface *`.

To picture my dilemma, I wrote this simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Person
{
    char *name;
    int age;
} Person;

Person *person_create(char *name, int age)
{
    Person *who = malloc(sizeof(Person));
    who->name   = strdup(name);
    who->age    = age;

    return who;
}

void person_get_old(Person *who)
{
    who->age += 30;
}

int main(void)
{
    Person *susan = person_create("Susan", 23);
    person_get_old(susan);
    printf("%i\n", susan->age);
}
```

This prints `53` just as expected, without me having to use pointer to pointer semantics. *What is the difference between my implementation and that one of SDL2*. This is no SDL2 question, as the one that answered my previous question could answer this without any knowledge of SDL2, so there seems to be some implementation detail I missed. Hope somebody can enlighten me.

Comment: choose a language tag, C and C++ are different. (Your last program is invalid in C++)

Comment: `auto init_window(SDL_Window **window)` is illegal in C++ (before C++17 anyway!) and C.  Your compiler should comment on this. Maybe you meant to return `void` ; or follow the model you used in your test program and have `SDL_Window *init_window(void)`

Comment: I can see how the first two are invalid in C (`auto` return type doesn't exist in C) and how the third one is invalid in C++ (the `malloc`), but I wonder why the first two are also supposed to be invalid in C++?

Comment: `auto` return type deduction for free functions was not added until C++17

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a simpler example to illustrate:

```
void foo(int p) //create new copy of int
{
    p = 0; //modify copy, original is unchanged
}
void bar(int* p) //create new copy of pointer
{
    *p = 0; //modify object pointer is set to
}
```

In your SDL example, you were trying to do `foo`. The goal was to set the pointer to a new value. However, you only copied the pointer and all changes were done to the copy.

In your `Person` example, you were doing `bar`. You had an object that was being pointed to, and you wanted to modify it. The correct way to do that is pass it by pointer (or reference).

Since you have an object you want to modify, you need to pass it by pointer (or reference). Since that object is a pointer itself, it will be a pointer to pointer.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between your implementation and that of SDL2 is that in your implementation returns a pointer and the calling code assigns it to a variable.

In the SDL2 implementation, the called function wants to store the pointer, and you want it stored in an existing pointer defined by the calling code.  It needs to know where to store the pointer, so it needs a *pointer* to the pointer.